# Add your own NSMenuItem to Finder menu

Tags: macos, cocoa, finder, nsmenu

I'm pretty sure this is possible since Dropbox has done it. Here's a screenshot:

http://content.screencast.com/users/calebjj/folders/Jing/media/eec88ca2-f9a9-4aa3-bd79-a78900087968/00000064.png

I'm looking to add an nsmenuitem to the finder menu when a user right clicks on a file in the finder window. Is this possible? If so how can this be done? And for that matter, so has TextWrangler (shown at the bottom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking at is a *service*. Look up "Services Menu" in the Apple help and you'll find out how your application can offer these services.

Comment: The problem with Services is that they only appear in the My App > Services menu (correct me if I'm wrong). I'd like to have the item appear when you right click a file.

Comment: Services also appear in contextual menus.

Comment: @ManOx - we all miss stuff sometimes, make us human, no need to feel bad.